# Monitorando eventos de um determinado diretório

Tags: java, monitoramento

Olá,

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicação que monitora eventos(criar, deletar e modificar arquivos) de um determinado diretório.

Estou usando a biblioteca apache.commons.io.monitor para me auxiliar.

Gerando o um .jar e executando em uma pasta teste funciona perfeitamente.

Porém quando jogo este .jar dentro do servidor (SYNOLOGY - Linux)  e executo, ele reconhece a pasta que é para monitorar, mas não reconhece nenhum evento. Como se nada estivesse acontecendo.

Classe **Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        EntityManager em = EntityManagerFactorySingleton.getInstance().createEntityManager();

        File dir = new File("//volume1//CLIENTES");

        FileAlterationObserver fao = new FileAlterationObserver(dir);
        fao.addListener(new FileAlterationListenerImpl(em, dir));

        FileAlterationMonitor monitor = new FileAlterationMonitor(1 * 1000);

        monitor.addObserver(fao);
        monitor.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

E dentro da minha classe **FileAlterationListenerImpl** ele vai armazenando os eventos num banco MySQL.

Existe alguma incompatibilidade dessa biblioteca com Linux? Procurei na documentação e não encontrei nada.

Comment: Como você sabe que ela reconhece a pasta que é para monitorar? Essa linha `File dir = new File("//volume1//CLIENTES");` não deveria ter as barras diagonais "escapadas" usando barra invertida? Por exemplo `"\\/volume1\\/CLIENTES"` Pesquise sobre sequências de escape no Java.

Comment: Boa tarde, sei que está reconhecendo a pasta correta pois fiz um teste, printando no console todas as pastas dentro de //volume1//CLIENTES e o resultado foi o que eu esperava.

Comment: Vou pesquisar sobre sequências de escape

Comment: usa o System.getProperty("file.separator") p/ não ter dúvidas.

Comment: Mesmo usando o  System.getProperty("file.separator") continua a mesma coisa. Reconhece a pasta correta, porém não reconhece nenhum evento.

Comment: Mesmo eu mapeando o server para a unidade Z:\, não reconhece nenhum evento

Comment: Galera, o problema não está no path. Na verdade, está até reconhecendo os eventos. Porém, demora um tempo aleatório para reconhecer esses eventos.  

Quando defini no código: new FileAlterationMonitor(1 * 1000);  seria para ele monitorar a  cada segundo, porém isso não está acontecendo no servidor. Alguém tem uma luz?